# Jquery Ajax and downloading dynamically created zip file

Tags: jquery, .net

I am using the below Jquery code to call the WebMethod defined in the code behind of asp.net form to process the request. The main parameter being passed is the DocUrls which is a JSON string containing all Urls of documents.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/ZipSearchResults",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: "{'docUrls':" + JSON.stringify(checkIds) + "," +
            "'hostWeb':'" + hostWeb + "'}",
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);

    },
    failure: function (xhr, status, error) {

        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        $('#example').text(err);
        $('#error').show();
    }
});
```

}

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string ZipSearchResults(string[] docUrls, string hostWeb)
    {
        _logHelper.LogInfo("Downloading and Zipping files for selected files" + docUrls, _sessionId);


        HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(new HttpCookie("fileDownload", "true") { Path = "/" });
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=DyanmicZipFile.zip");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

        ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipOutputStream(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
        zipOutputStream.SetLevel(0); //0-9, 9 being the highest level of compression
        zipOutputStream.UseZip64 = ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.UseZip64.Off;

        var Web = new Uri(hostWeb);
        var context = HttpContext.Current;

        foreach (String fileNamePair in docUrls)
        {
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                using (
                    var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetS2SClientContextWithWindowsIdentity(Web,
                        context.Request.LogonUserIdentity))
                {
                    wc.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                    using (Stream wcStream = wc.OpenRead(fileNamePair))
                    {
                        ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipEntry entry =
                            new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipEntry(
                                ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipEntry.CleanName(fileNamePair));

                        zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(entry);

                        int count = wcStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        while (count > 0)
                        {
                            zipOutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                            count = wcStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            if (!HttpContext.Current.Response.IsClientConnected)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        zipOutputStream.Close();

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;  // Gets or sets a value indicating whether to send HTTP content to the client.
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); ;


        return "Success";
    }
```

The response being returned is all garbage indicating it to be zip file. How do I go about downloading the zip file?

Request

Request Headers

```
Cache-Control:private
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=DyanmicZipFile.zip
Content-Type:application/zip
Date:Tue, 08 Dec 2015 17:45:02 GMT
Persistent-Auth:true
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?RDpcU2FpXEJyYW5keXdpbmUuU1AuRUNNU2VhcmNoXEJyYW5keXdpbmUuU1AuRUNNU2VhcmNoV2ViXFBhZ2VzXERlZmF1bHQuYXNweFxaaXBTZWFyY2hSZXN1bHRz?=
```

Response

```
PK¡eGbhttp://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.com/sites/Clients/Migration%20Library/Formation/2811.pdfés%PDF-1.4
%¾ºÛî
1 0 obj
<</Type /Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/OpenAction 5 0 R/Metadata 62 0 R>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type /Pages/Kids [ 3 0 R 8 0 R 10 0 R 12 0 R 14 0 R 16 0 R 21 0 R 23 0 R 25 0 R 27 0 R 29 0 R 31 0 R 33 0 R ]/Count 13>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Resources <</ProcSet [ /PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI ]/Font <</F1 6 0 R>>/XObject <</X1 7 0 R>>>>/Type /Page/MediaBox [ 0 0 612 792 ]/Parent 2 0 R/Rotate 0/Contents [ 36 0 R 37 0 R ]>>
endobj
4 0 obj
[ 3 0 R /XYZ 0 842 0 ]
```

Comment: Can you post your web method?

Comment: Why don't you just create the zip file and save it to your server, and just return the url back to the ui and do a redirect?

Comment: I was really hoping not to do that. Was looking forward for an alternative solution. If that is the case, might go for it.

Comment: Have you tried adding `Response.BinaryWrite(zipOutputStream);` and `Response.End();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only viable and reliable option was the save the zip file to the server and pass the url to the browser. That fixed my issue!

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that the server returns the proper `Content-Disposition` header:

```
Content-Disposition: attachement; filename.zip
```

As well as the proper Content-Type:

```
Content-Type: application/zip
```

I'm not sure if jQuery is going to be able to handle the result but the file should be downloading automatically.

You cannot do a "saveFile" in JavaScript. It has to be initiated by the server.

Comment: The server side returns data as a stream of garbage characters are shown. the issue is with the response. Need to find an alternate way to access the data.

Comment: Can you provide us with the HTTP Headers of the request and the HTTP Headers of the response?

Comment: Added request and response to the actual question. The response is just garbage characters and it is very huge to copy and paste over here.

Comment: It looks like the server is actually sending you a PDF.

Comment: Added web method to the code which is getting called.